# Doctrine 2 fatal error when adding new association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two object classes, Session and Speaker, with a many-to-many association. When I want to add a speaker to a session, I use this code:

```
109   $session->getSpeakers()->add($speaker);
110   $speaker->getSessions()->add($session);
```

**This works fine for existing sessions.** Now when I instantiate a new session and then try to add speakers the same way, I get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on null in C:\###\api\sessions\update.php:109
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\###\api\sessions\update.php on line 109
```

I presume this is because the new session doesn't have any speakers yet and thus returns null when I call `getSpeakers()`.

However I can't find anything in the Doctrine Docs about how to circumvent this. Did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you [initialized your collection](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) in the constructor?

```
// missing parts skipped for brevity
public function __construct(...)
{
    // ...
    $this->speakers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Anyway your code is poor quality in terms of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). You should have methods called:

```
addSpeaker(Speaker $speaker)
addSession(Session $session)
```

so only the object itself knows how to handle the collection. For the time being you leak its internal details outside the class which is bad ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation), because it decreases code maintainability in time.

Comment: Have you initialized the `$speakers` as well? There's no magic here.

Comment: ...I totally did not forget that. At all. :D Thanks Mike, works fine now!

Comment: Good to hear, please mark my answer as the solution if it fits.